# Encrypt personal data with a second hash from the password while already having a hash stored

Tags: python, encryption, sqlalchemy, python-cryptography

The database looks like this:

```
class Users(UserMixin,db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100))
    hash_password = db.Column(db.Text)
    secret_content = db.Column(db.Text)
```

The secret content is highly confidential, I don't even want the admin to know the content of the data.
My idea was to encode the content like this:

```
class Users(UserMixin,db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100))
    hash_password = db.Column(db.Text)
    secret_content = db.Column(db.Text)
    def __init__(self, username , password_hash, secret_content, key):
        cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
        self.username = username 
        self.secret_content = cipher_suite.encrypt(bytes(secret_content))
        self.hash_password = password_hash
```

The key used to encrypt the data should be different for each user.
I wanted to create the key by hashing the password with sha256.
**However, the hash is already stored in the user for login purposes.
Therefore I would use another hashing algorithm, MD5 for example.**

The issue I see by doing that is that if a hacker is able to find/decypher this hash then he would be able to also extract the real password because at that point you can eliminate a lot of possibilities when the hacker brute forces the password.

Do I have other options or will I need to ask the user for a second unrelated password?

Comment: Sure there are way, but how do you image this to work within your application? I guess this is a web application. If the user logs in their password would be sent in the clear and hashed. You could derive an encryption key from the password with PBKDF2 and a different random salt. But now the user can only see their secret content when they log in, because that is the only time the server has the cleartext password to derive the key. Persisting the key over multiple requests on the server defeats the purpose. You could do the key derivation on the client in JS and decrypt it on the client.

Comment: Btw, MD5 is not an algorithm that should be used nowadays.

Comment: Thank you for proposing PBKDF2
It is indeed a web application
But now let's say you encrypt the word "strawberry" and store it in the database.
The hacker knows that the word you encoded should be strawberry so he bruteforces which passwords are eligible to be the original password and stores these passwords in a pw-list.
The hacker has also access to the sha256 hash of the password.
The hacker applies sha256 to the passwords in pw-list and compares it to the stored hash in the database. The hacker has now found the password.
Is this case a security risk or would it take ages to find it?

Comment: >You could do the key derivation on the client in JS and decrypt it on the client
That would mean that the key is visible at client side, wouldn't that make it vulnerable for hackers?
I would store the PBKDF2 key on a server-side session, which will drop when the session ends

Comment: PBKDF2 is there to derive keys. You generate two random salts during user registration. One salt is used with the password to derive that password hash for authentication purposes and the other will be used to derive with the password the encryption key. Even with PBKDF2 it is important to use either very complex or very long passwords. PBKDF2 and a sensible password rule set would severely reduce the probability of a successful brute force attack.

Comment: You will have to include a server-based session invalidation after a specific inactivity timeout or dedicated logout in order to purge the encryption key. That could work, sure. Now that I think about it, client-based encryption would work, but the password or key would have to be persisted for the duration of the session (e.g. in `sessionStorage`). These credentials are reachable when the application is vulnerable to XSS, but other than that safe from "hackers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments from @Artjom B.

Add salt to the key.
Encrypt key with PBKDF2 to encode the personal data with.
Encrypt the same key with sh256 for user login.